# ¿Cómo puedo desactivar los mensaje que lanza el hibernate?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Tengo esto y me gustaría saber cómo puedo desaparecer estos mensajes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de aplicación es y qué librería de logging utilizas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes cambiarlo en tu archivo de configuración de hibernate, en la propiedad **hibernate.show_sql** debes tenerlo activado a true, ponlo en **false**:

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```